# OOP principle: which is better? Operation with itself, or operation with other object?

Tags: php, oop

sorry, I cant really describe it better. Here is a graphical system:

```
class Point
{
    private $x, $y, $color;

    public function draw(Graphic $graphicEngine)
    {
        $graphicEngine->setPixel ($this->x, $this->y, $this->color);
    }
}

class Graphic
{
    private $points; // array of Point

    public function draw()
    {
        foreach ($this->points as $point)
        {
            $point->draw($this);
        }
    }
}
```

my colleague says its bad. It has a circular reference (`Point` knows about `Graphic` and vice-versa). He said "not the subject (`Point`) do something with itself, but something happens WITH the (`Point`) subject", and the `Point` should be an independent living thing. His solution:

```
class Point
{
    public $x, $y, $color;
}

class Graphic
{
    private $points; // array of Point

    public function draw()
    {
        foreach ($this->points as $point)
        {
            $this->setPixel ($point->x, $point->y, $point->color);
        }
    }
}
```

its separated, OK. But in my point of view, there is a `Point`. How can it draw itself then?

Comment: colleague has a point here (pun intended).

Comment: `$this->draw($this);` Huh? (Also, it may be that there's a need for a third object here, as is somewhat hinted at by the naming, e.g. `Graphic $graphicEngine`. Is a Graphic actually a GraphicEngine? Is that something that should really have a collection of points?)

Comment: Why should a point be able to draw itself? It's just a dumb data object

Comment: @MattGibson: $point->draw($this); I misstyped

Comment: I think there should be three classes here: `Point`, `Graphic` and `GraphicEngine`. Graphic is a collection of points, and both can use the engine to be drawn, or either be passed to the engine to draw them.